# VBA Pause code and wait for user interaction

Tags: vba, excel

I have code where I have added an error box that pops up based on certain conditions. The conditions are:

```
If Range (Q2:Q) = "" Then
ErrorFrame.Visible = True
```

When the error frame pops up, there are two options I want that I have added buttons for:

1. Continue:
   Continue will continue with the macro regardless if there is data in column Q
2. Stop:
   Stop will end the macro so the user can input the data into column Q and rerun the macro

I also would like it so that when the error frame pops up, the code is paused and does not continue yet until the user chooses one of the options.

Would anyone be able to give me an example of how this could work? I'm having trouble thinking of how to write this. Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What is `ErrorFrame`?  If it is a userform, make sur that you `.Show` it like `ErrorFrame.Show vbModal`; that will treat it like a dialog and execution in the main sub will not continue until the form is closed.

Comment: You could probably use the build in function [`msgbox()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/139z2azd(v=vs.90).aspx) for the error box. It will also wait on an input from the user, so it does everything you need.

Comment: The ErrorFrame is a frame I drew on the userform. It pops up if column Q is empty. And I could use the msgbox, but I really would like to do it this way if possible. I have gotten the error box to pop up, and if I click "Stop" it terminates the program, now I just have to find out how to just continue the Sub if "Continue" is clicked. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out myself:

```
If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("Q:Q")) = 0 Then
UserForm1.ErrorFrame.Visible = True
    Do While UserForm1.ErrorFrame.Visible = True
    DoEvents
    Loop
    If ContinueFlag = True Then GoTo Line1
End If

Line1:
```

Basically for the continue button I just added a flag on it so when clicked it would make the flag true. Then in the function as you can see, when the flag is true it will go to Line 1, which then continues the code and exits the `Do While` loop.

May not be the most efficient way, I'm sure, but let me know what you guys think and if there is a better way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

If you trying to bring up a form the syntax should be the following:

`frmMyForm.Show vbModal`

The `vbModal` allows it to pause the current procedure and move onto the displayed form.